# How to analyse SQL Query using Python?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, python-re

I want to analyze SQL query to know which hard coded values are belonging to which column? For e.g I have a following SQL query:-

```
SELECT *
FROM (
      SELECT DISTINCT id 
              ,substring([data], 0, 497) AS [Instructions]
              ,'500' AS [Care_Code]
              ,cast(id AS VARCHAR) + cast(number AS VARCHAR) + 'pp' AS key
      FROM people
      WHERE ([data] LIKE '%communicated %')
   
     
      UNION ALL
     
      SELECT DISTINCT Patientid
              ,substring(pp, 0, 497) AS [Instructions]
              ,'500' AS [Care_Code]
              ,cast(id AS VARCHAR) + cast(number AS VARCHAR) + 'aa' AS key
      FROM people
      WHERE  Instructions LIKE '%[A-Z]%'
```

I want the output to be like:-

```
Harcoded_value    Column_Name
500               Care_Code
%communicated %   data
%[A-Z]%           Instructions
```

Example 2:-

Query :-

```
select distinct eid, count(distinct d.pid)   
 from SOAP s      
inner join demographics d on s.pid=d.pid     
inner join PS p on p.providerId=s.pid     
where      
p.npi in ('1316987761','1437366473','1912915638','1740253822')    
and Convert(datetime,Convert(varchar,EncounterDate,101)) >='08/01/2016'    
and  Convert(datetime,Convert(varchar,EncounterDate,101)) <= '07/31/2017'   
group by eid
```

Expected Output:-

```
 Harcoded_value                                              Column
  ('1316987761','1437366473','1912915638','1740253822')       p.npi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
import re
import pandas as pd

s = """SELECT *
FROM (
      SELECT DISTINCT id 
              ,substring([data], 0, 497) AS [Instructions]
              ,'500' AS [Care_Code]
              ,cast(id AS VARCHAR) + cast(number AS VARCHAR) + 'pp' AS key
      FROM people
      WHERE ([data] LIKE '%communicated %')


      UNION ALL

      SELECT DISTINCT Patientid
              ,substring(pp, 0, 497) AS [Instructions]
              ,'500' AS [Care_Code]
              ,cast(id AS VARCHAR) + cast(number AS VARCHAR) + 'aa' AS key
      FROM people
      WHERE  Instructions LIKE '%[A-Z]%'
      and p.npi in ('1316987761','1437366473','1912915638','1740253822')
           """

results = {}
for value in re.findall(r"(([A-Za-z.]+ in )*(((\[.*\]|\w*) LIKE )*\(*'%*.+%*'\)*( AS (\w|\[.*\])*)*))", s):
    splited_values = value[0].split(" ")
    val = "".join(splited_values[2:])
    if "AS" in value[0] and splited_values[2] != "key":
        results[re.sub("\'|\"", "", splited_values[0])] = re.sub(r"\W", "", val)
    elif "LIKE" in value[0] or "in" in value[0]:
        val = val[:-1] if val[-1] == ")" and val[0] != "(" else val
        results[re.sub("\'|\"", "", val)] = re.sub(r"\[|\]", "", splited_values[0])


df = pd.DataFrame(results.items(), columns=["Harcoded_value", "Column_Name"])
print(df)
```

Output

```
                                 Harcoded_value       Column_Name
                                            500         Care_Code
                                  communicated%              data
                                        %[A-Z]%       nstructions
   (1316987761,1437366473,1912915638,1740253822)            p.npi
```

This code will extract all values that contain '' from the query and the words before the LIKE or after the AS and not by the name `key` and will store it in the results dictionary.
After collecting all the values it will create a DataFrame with the columns  `"Harcoded_value"` and `"Column_Name"`

Comment: Thanks @Leo for the amazing answer can I do it in the same way for IN keyword as well !

Comment: Thanks for this beautiful solution